# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable (QGIS 3)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, error

I'm getting this error when trying to run the following code:

```
line = iface.activeLayer()

a = processing.run("qgis:fieldcalculator", {'INPUT':line,'FIELD_NAME':'len','FIELD_TYPE':1,'FIELD_LENGTH':10,'FIELD_PRECISION':3,'NEW_FIELD':True,'FORMULA':' $length ','OUTPUT':'memory:'})
layer1 =a['OUTPUT']
featparede = layer1.getFeatures()
parede = []
for f in featparede:
    parede.append(f['len'])
print (parede)
```

Now I have shutted down the Pc and restarted it. The code worked once but in the second time it gave the error. Now it only gives the error.

This is the complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: To what line of your code does the error refer?

Comment: I run the script using qgis 3.10 and I didn't get the error. You can give more details.

Comment: the error refer to the "print(parede)" line . Can this be a bug from my Qgis or Pc? I'm using Qgis 3.6. Also.. another code of mine that did not used to get this error, now it is getting it..

Comment: it always refer to the print command.

Comment: Is the space between `print` and `(parede)` a typo?

Comment: Is this your whole code? Do you have variable `print` that happens to be a tuple somewhere in your code? Something like `print = (2, 4)`?